# Dotcms: how to set different detail page for single structure per host

Tags: velocity, dotcms

It's a question for every DotCms structure, but consider for example the **News** structure on my DotCms 2.5 installation: the system lets me choose only a single page as "Detail Page".

Since I don't want to create a new structure for every host I'll create, but I want to use the "detail page" mechanism, how can simulate it?

I can't find a way to pass the path to the .html / .vtl template like for example for the  [login macro (look at $loginFormSourceCode parameter)](http://dotcms.com/docs/latest/UserLoginForm)

Thanks

[image: DotCms structure image]

Answer (score 1):

Dotcms will forward your URLmap to the **uri** of the selected detail page on the host which is being viewed.  So, for example, you have your news structure mapped to /news/detail.html on a server that runs multiple sites, site1 and site2.  When a user views a selected news item, each site will then forward the user to a detail page local to its site.

So site1 will forward news items to:

```
site1.dotcms.com/news/details.html
```

And site2 will forward news items to:

```
site1.dotcms.com/news/details.html
```

These are different pages on the servers (though they can share the same .vtl or code to display the content).

Comment: I think I haven't explained well, I know about this "modus operandi" that you mentioned, but I meant another thing:
I want that different hosts will have different news detail structure page, in the structure section I can only choose one specific of a specific host: I don't want to share all assets of that single webpage, I mean, the css and all other resources cannot be the same.